# Will a battery designed for northern climates perform poorly in hot weather?

Tags: battery

I need a new battery and was recommended [this battery](https://www.sears.com/diehard-gold-automotive-battery-group-size-24f-price/p-02850823000P). The product page says the following:

> Designed specifically for Northern climates
>
> Pretty much the only place this battery won't fit in is south of the Mason-Dixon line. It's designed specifically for Northern climates (sorry, Southerners), making elitism its only known fault.
>
> Available in the following states: CT, DE, MA, MD, ME, NH, NJ, NY, OH, PA, RI, VT and WV

Will a battery designed for cold weather perform poorly enough in hot weather that they won’t even sell it in southern states? Even northern states have hot summers nowadays.

Comment: Your link is broken, typically batteries up north have more Cold Cranking Amps, no reason you cannot use it in southern climates.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Moab in his comment. There's nothing to worry about, as long as it has enough CCA, however, I would say you'd be wasting money getting it.

The important thing for batteries is CCA (Cold Cranking Amps).
This is how much power the battery can provide when cold.

When a battery is cold, the chemistry it uses is slowed down so it cannot provide as much power until it's warmed up a bit, manufacturers combat this by generally just making the battery more powerful and/or using different chemistry (i.e. if it loses 30% when cold, make it large enough that its still enough to start the car).
Similar things can happen if the battery gets hot, however, a hot summers day is not an issue, only if the battery gets very hot.

In your case (725 CCA), you will be fine using this battery so long as it has more than the CCA requirements of your car, however, keep in mind, extra doesn't provide any benefit, and since your in a warm climate, there's no need to spend extra on a battery like this.
Any run of the mill average priced battery will be fine as long as it meets the minimum CCA rating your car needs.